# How to transfer file from MacOS to Ubuntu Server?

Tags: ssh, xubuntu, mac

I tried the following command using my Mac Terminal

```
scp -rp /path/file user@SERVER_IP:/path/destination/folder
```

It gives me following error:

```
user@SERVER_IP: Permission denied (public key).
lost connection
```

Is there any ports that i am missing to open?

Comment: Hello, are you able to connect to the server over ssh?

Comment: I am using GC Compute Engine. I am able to connect using SSH button on VM Instance on GC

Comment: "Is there any ports that i am missing to open?" no you are missing a public key. Please read up on how security works in regards to scp.

Comment: See for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/803908/how-do-i-add-an-ssh-key-to-a-google-compute-cloud-vps-instance But be careful. Doing it incorrectly can lock you out.

Comment: I am not able to rdp my ubuntu VM instance which i have created on Google Cloud  getting following error https://prnt.sc/rf91cq

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filezilla or WinSCP alternative for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/987769/filezilla-or-winscp-alternative-for-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, scp asks for a password. To avoid this, or to automate file copying in scripts, public key authentication is usually used.
The basic idea is to create a key pair on the client and copy the public key to the server into an [authorized keys file.](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/authorized_keys)

Sources: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/scp#configuring-public-key-authentication

Answer (score 0):

No you are not missing any ports.

Here is an answer:

You need to check if the remote directory(Where you are posting) has permissions for other users.

If not, run: sudo chmod 777 [remote directory]

This should work!